# Iphone SDK: recording system sounds

Tags: iphone, audio, system, record

currently im developing a drumm app. The only thing that's left to do, is a "looper".

I want to make the looper by "recording the system". (recording the drum sounds)
I know how to record the mic ( Im using this to record sound:

```
 TempRecFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:@"VoiceFile"]]];

        recorder1 = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:TempRecFile settings:nil error:nil];
        [recorder1 setDelegate:self];
        [recorder1 prepareToRecord];
        [recorder1 record];
```

)

How can i do the same thing, but with system sounds??

Thank's in advance!

-DD

Comment: please, someone answer!! the upvotes aren't really a help :)

Comment: add a bounty to it ??

Answer (score 0):

maybe duplicated with this post ?
[Record Internal Sound iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620131/record-internal-sound-iphone-sdk)

This not gonna be easy but still possible.If you are confident with C++ , you can check FMOD library which also allows you to write to raw sound buffer. If you don't want to use 3-rd party library , you can check apple's CoreAudio framework.

Hope it will Help!