# Record Internal Sound using iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, audio, audiotoolbox

I am making an app that requires internal sound to be recorded.

Any solution?

Comment: you should give more description......

Answer (score 2):

The is no public iOS API that will allow you to record all internal sound that an app or the device can make.  Only certain types of internal sound can be recorded, for instance sounds produced by an app using Audio Queues or the RemoteIO Audio Unit.

For recording external sound, Apple's SpeakHere sample code might be appropriate.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to record these sounds?

Comment: Apple's SpeakHere sample shows how to record sounds from your Audio Queue record buffers.  You can do the same with your uncompressed Audio Queue play buffers to record them.

Comment: I'm sorry but when it comes to sound on iOS I am a total newbie and that made no sense to me

Comment: Do you think that you could help me with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476697/how-to-record-user-generated-sound-output-on-iphone)?

Answer (score 0):

[ReplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit) framework records screen video and **audio from the app** and microphone. However ReplayKit is incompatible with AVPlayer content. It's available in iOS 9.0 and higher.