# How to record user generated sound output on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I have a series of sounds that a user will play, rearrange, and edit etc. while using my app.  When the user is finished, I want them to be able to save their work and record it to an mp3.

I don't want to play it through speakers and record it with the mic since that will result in low sound quality and interference.  I cannot think of any ways of doing this that doesn't require extra hardware and/or a computer.

How can I do this using just their device?

Comment: This can't be done with a few simple lines of code.  Instead, a textbook on digital signal processing or computer music would be a good starting point.  There's also a largish book on Core Audio.

Comment: i was afraid of that -.-

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say it cant be done with AVFoundation.

My suggestion is to use Audio Units, and transform all your interactions to an audio graph. at some point you set a render notify on the RemoteIO so every time it renders sounds to the speakers you get a callback where you can write it down those frames/packets/data into a file.

I will probably suggest to use AAC(m4a) over MP3. I am not very fond of MP3, and to be honest as far as I know the sdk does not provide encoding to MP3, probably due to licensing issues. I could be wrong though. Check this sample code below, probably the best sample code you will ever find on Audio units on the web.

[AudioGraph by Tom Zic](http://zerokidz.com/audiograph/Home.html)