# iOS How can I record internal audio?

Tags: ios, core-audio

Is it possible to record background sound by an app? If so, what is the key technology? (Core Audio?)

What I want to do is below..

1. Open BBC radio on safari.
2. Open the recording app. At the time, safari runs in the background.
3. Record the sound by the recording app.

I tried to find solutions like using "Novocaine" but I still haven't the faintest idea.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried getting the stream URL for BBC Radio and record directly from the stream? If you can find the right URL, something like [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) could help you actually stream the audio. Then it is only up to you to record what you get from the stream. This is a much more realistic approach to accomplishing your goal.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will apply this approach to make it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [Record Internal Sound iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620131/record-internal-sound-iphone-sdk) .

And no, you cannot do it by any public API - using a non-public API will result in your app getting rejected and not allowed into the Apple App Store.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not know the duplicate question. I understand that it is not allowed. But "Apple's SpeakHere sample" looks useful. I will check it out. Thank you so much.